# subdirectories in django admin listings

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have an app that posts assets(tactics) to an html page. Each page has a job number (e.g. AC14245) and several tactics. Additionally, there are several clients, each with numerous pages. To facilitate this, I have a simple model that looks like this:

```
class TacticEntry(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    cell_number = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    posting_page = models.ForeignKey(TacticPage)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    post_type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=POST_CHOICES)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    add_pdf = models.NullBooleanField()
    link_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    add_html = models.NullBooleanField()
    link_html = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    add_report = models.NullBooleanField()
    link_report = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    add_zip = models.NullBooleanField()
    link_zip = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__ (self):
            return u'%s %s' % (self.client, self.job_title)
```

As expected, in the admin, this returns a TacticEntry list that lists tactics as follows:

```
ACME AC111111
ACME AC111112
ACME AC111113
...
```

which quickly becomes problematic due to the large number of records. Is there a way I can configure either the admin, or the return statement in my model to create subdirectories/folders in the admin so that each clients tactics are grouped in their own folder?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I was looking for was a mechanism for organizing the records. The admin filter functionality is exactly that.